# How to sort all dropdownLists by name in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to automatically sort all dropdownLists in ASP.net MVC project?

I don't want to go one by one and sort them explicitly. Is there a way to do this automatically on all dropdownLists in the project?

Comment: Short answer: No.  Long answer: Maybe, but you would have to code an extension to the DropDownList html helper.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `HtmlHelperExtensions` class that has an extension method that does what you want. Something like this:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString SortedDropDownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList)
    {
        return htmlHelper.DropDownList(name, selectList.OrderBy(x => x.Text));
    }
}
```

Whatever namespace you stick the helper in, make sure it's added to `configuration\system.web.webPages.razor\pages\namespaces` in the web.config found in your `\Views` folder so that you can use it in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You could create HtmlHelperExtension class as friism sugested, or you could create extension method on SelectList like this:

```
public static class SortedList
{
        public static void SortList(this SelectList selectList, SortDirection direction)
        {
            //sort content of selectList
        }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
var sel = new SelectList(new List<string> {"john", "mary", "peter"});
sel.SortList(SortDirection.Ascending);
```

Either way, you are going to change every line of code where you want to sort those lists.